# attempting to parse a ICal RRule string

Tags: php

```
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TU,WE,FR;UNTIL=20110713T075959Z;WKST=SU
```

I'm building a drupal site and the Date module outputs this code, which I need to display on a page in a more readable format.

I just want to get the days and the end date which is the UNTIL.

I'm not sure how to approach it. I'm not very good with regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just cheat and parse it as a query string:

```
parse_str(strtr($YOUR_STRING, ';', '&'), $data);
```

And then you can further process it, e.g. split the `BYDAY`:

```
$byDays = explode(',', $data['BYDAY']);
```